# Dropdownlist population from ASP datasource and stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, data-binding, dataset

If a dropdown list and dataset (based on stored procedure) are created in an ASP page, With a session based parameter.
Shouldn't the list populate when the session variable is set to a value that returns results in the proc and the `databind()` is called?
 Or is there something else to do?
  I was attempting things like `dataset.select()` but wondering how that happens.
  It's all in the pageload.  Please see code if perhaps I missed something obvious.

Note:  the reason I create the datasource in the ASPx page rather than in the codebehind is because I will be creating a lot of them and it's much quicker that way, but maybe that's not a good way.

The ASP is

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddClinic" runat="server"OnSelectedIndexChanged=" 
      ddClinic_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="dsClinics" 
      DataTextField="ClinicName" DataValueField="ClinicID" AutoPostBack="True">
      <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select One</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsClinics" runat="server" ConnectionString="
      <$ConnectionStrings:coPC3PaymentConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetClinicsForUser" 
      SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DbType="Int32" Name="userID" SessionField="Userid" 
              Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LbMsg.Text" DbType="String" Direction="Output" 
                  Name="ErrorMsg" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So,  in the Codebehind C# shouldn't this make it fill?  (assuming the parameters return data in the SP?

```
      Session["User"] = PC3User;

                Session["MultiClinics"] = 1;

                ddClinic.DataBind();
```

Again,  sorry for dumb question but all the examples I'm finding are with the datasource being created in the codebehind.  Is that needed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Questions can be removed from this board, but I don't think this one will help anyone else because I found that my problem was simple and NOT related to the dataabind - I was simply referencing the session variable by the wrong name

```
Session["User"] vs  <asp:SessionParameter DbType="Int32" Name="user**ID**"
```

My apologies if you wasted time, and I will be more careful.  This has happened a couple times to me.  I will check all string values as they will not be caught in build.